# Python. Socket closes after one input

Tags: python, sockets

I am doing an simple Python socket server and client that need to be able to receive few inputs and not losing connection. I can input one command but after receiving the reply the connection is lost. How can i keep it alive?

Client code

```
import socket  
import sys 
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except sockets.error , msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket, Error code:' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message :' +     msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Created'

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8888
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:

    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
    sys.exit()

print 'Ip address of ' + host + ' is ' + remote_ip

s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip

message = raw_input('Sladu inn skipun :')

try :
   s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
   print 'Send failed'
   sys.exit()

print 'Message send successfully'

reply = s.recv(4096)

print reply

s.close()
```

Server code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import socket
import sys
from thread import *
import glob

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'


s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'


def clientthread(conn):

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data == "show dir":
            reply = glob.glob('*.*')
        else: 
           reply ="Þessi skipun hefur ekki verið forrituð"
           if not data:
              break

        conn.send(str(reply))


while 1:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])


    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Comment: The indentation in your example is all messed up. It's impossible to know for sure what code belongs to what block.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the formatting. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: You can have an else statement on a while loop in python?  Eww.  Here's to hoping your indentation isn't fixed.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Fixed i hope.

Comment: @xaxxon: Yes, you can have an `else` on a `while` loop, and it's very useful. (Well, more often useful with `for` than `while`, but then `for` is more often useful than `for` anyway…) It's explained in [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), but basically, it lets you use `break` without needing the `found = True` flag or other out-of-band way of distinguishing "broke out early because of success" vs. "finished the loop because we never found anything" that's so common in C.

Comment: Even with this fix, your code isn't going to work. [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html), so that `conn.recv(1024)` could easily return `"show d"` the first time, and then `"ir"` the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server code looks okay. But your client is only sending one message and then exiting. Which closes the connection.

Try something like this in your client code:

```
while True:
    message = raw_input('Sladu inn skipun :')
    try :
        s.sendall(message)
        print s.recv(1024)
    except socket.error:
        print 'Send failed'
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: +1. I would also add the "reply = s.recv(4096)" in the same while-loop since you are expecting the server to send a response too.

Comment: True, Manoj, @HundurinnNero: If the answer worked for you it's a good idea to accept it as the correct one. It helps future searchers.